# Received 'Stack Exchange inbox' email that's outside of my settings

Tags: support

I've visited tex.SE on the 15th, 16th, 17th and obviously today, but on the 17th at 12:12 I received a **2 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox** email.

My settings are set to email me unread items weekly. I was under the impression this meant I only received an email for entries that had been left unread in my inbox for about a week - am I mistaken?

Comment: Visiting the site is not enough. To mark items as "read" you must explicitly click the StackExchange box. You sure you did that? Taken [from the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) - *Bear in mind that we will only email you if you have not checked your global inbox in that time interval*

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, but I guess if the email is sent at a fixed time every week then I may have just missed the cut-off...?

Comment: Yep - for example if you last clicked at 10 PM, the email is sent at 12 AM and you got 2 new notifications during this time it explains what happened.